# how to get dm_db_index_usage_stats in linq?

Tags: sql, linq

I need get the last updated record from all the table

i return query here in sql

```
SELECT OBJECT_NAME(OBJECT_ID) AS DatabaseName, last_user_update,*FROM sys.dm_db_index_usage_stats
```

How to convert to above query to linq when i tried below linq 
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/3630f374-6d3f-44ff-aec5-8e6463b90368/linq-and-sql-metadata-built-in-functions?forum=vblanguage
 here i am unable to find the dm_db_index_usage_stats in linq

Comment: linq is an abstraction over databases. dm_db_index-Usage_stats is implementation specific. I'd be surprised if this what exposed through linq.

Comment: yes i want to get last update records  for all the table  for specific database how to write query in linq? is that possible?